# Find min in Linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to find the min in a linked list of Vertices. This is what I wrote, but it is faulty. I don't get an error, but my program doesn't work and I think this is the source of the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
      Iterator itr = vertices.iterator();
      Vertex smallest= getVertex(s);
      Vertex temp;
      while (itr.hasNext()){
          smallest=(Vertex)itr.next();
           if(itr.hasNext() && vertices.size()> 1 ){//there are at least 2 vertices left
                temp = (Vertex)itr.next();
                if (temp.distance< smallest.distance){
                    smallest = temp;
                }
          }
     }
```

Comment: "but my program doesn't work" do you mean it gives you the wrong answer?

Comment: It's supposed to give me the shortest path on a graph, and the path it gives me is not the shortest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are consuming two elements from the iterator on each iteration (via `itr.next()`), so this means you are only comparing some elements:

```
1----2----3-----4-----5-----6
\----/    \-----/     \-----/
```

You compare 1 and 2; 3 and 4; 5 and 6; but not 2 and 3; 4 and 5.

The easiest way to solve this is to keep the previous vertex:

```
Vertex prev = itr.next();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  Vertex current = itr.next();

  // Compare prev and current

  prev = current;
}
```

Note also that you can avoid the casts `(Vertex)` if you declare the iterator with a type parameter:

```
Iterator<Vertex> itr = vertices.iterator();
```

Comment: Better yet would be to use an enhanced `for` loop: `for (Vertex current : vertices)`

Comment: @Andreas except that you don't want to process the first element by itself in the loop.

Comment: That's why you would initialize `min` to null before the loop, which incidentally also fixes the bug that code throws `NoSuchElementException` if `vertices` is empty. You then change `if` statement to `if (min == null || current.distance < min.distance) { min = current; }`, and decide what code should do if `min` is null after the loop, e.g. `return Optional.ofNullable(min)`

Comment: You answer of `prev = current` and code comment of `Compare prev and current` seems incorrect, since goal is *"to find the min in a linked list of Vertices"*, aka the `smallest` variable in question code. It is not the goal to compare adjacent values.

Comment: @Andreas ah, I must have seen the question I wanted to see.